# How to use OpenMP in Xcode 9.0

Tags: c++, c, xcode, openmp

Does anyone know how to enable the use of OpenMP in Xcode 9.0?

In Xcode 8, I procide as described in [this tutorial](http://www.swiftsight.tech/configure-openmp-on-xcode-8/) but it doesn't work anymore in Xcode 9.0 ...

The error is : `clang-5.0: error: cannot specify -o when generating multiple output files`

Thanks in advance for help

Comment: "It doesn't work" is not q sufficient problem description.  [ask]

Comment: That link is broken. But this outlines the steps: http://antonmenshov.com/2017/09/09/clang-openmp-setup-in-xcode/. Only the “Enable Index-While-Building Functionality”, discussed below, is not included in that site.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the problem is in flag -index-store-path
In build settings > build options set Enable Index-While-Building Functionality to No

Comment: This works. The option is called COMPILER_INDEX_STORE_ENABLE.

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 11.7

There are 2 ways (no need to use both)

1. using `llvm`
2. using `libomp`

Follows `libomp` :

Install `libomp`

```
brew install libomp
```

Write some code:

```
#include <omp.h>

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
      printf("Hello from thread %d, nthreads %d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), omp_get_num_threads());
    }
}
```

In build setting make following changes

- Other linker flags: `-lomp`
- Header Search paths: `/usr/local/opt/libomp/include`
- Library Search paths: `/usr/local/opt/libomp/lib`
- Other C flags: `-Xpreprocessor AND -fopenmp`

[image: OpenMP]

Mission success:

```
2020-09-30 17:23:58.449045+0800 QRGenerator2[24352:3549441] Metal API Validation Enabled
Hello from thread 0, nthreads 4
Hello from thread 1, nthreads 4
Hello from thread 3, nthreads 4
Hello from thread 2, nthreads 4
```